# In what ways the Way removes the craving?

Tags: eightfold-path, craving

Buddha says the Way of Eightfold path removes the craving. I am looking for a short summary of ways the Way removes the craving.
My question is : In which ways does the Way removes the craving ? How does the Way removes the craving ? ( For example if the answer is by holding right view then I would like to know How does holding right view removes craving ?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> For example if the answer is by holding right view then I would like to know How does holding right view removes craving ?

It's no coincidence that Right View is mentioned first in the Noble Eightfold Path (N8P).

We crave because of Wrong View: where one of its manifestation is the [Four Perversions](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/an/an04/an04.049.than.html) (seeing impermanent things as permanent, dukkha as pleasure, not-Self as self, and un-attractive as attractive).

But even with Right View, one still needs other limbs of the N8P to reinforce/strengthen one's practice toward a complete abandonment of craving, through the 3 gateways of moral virtues/mental discipline/wisdom (i.e. cultivate Sila/moral virtues thru Right Speech, Right Livelihood, etc.; cultivate mental discipline thru Right Effort, Right Concentration, etc.).

For a thorough analysis on the purpose of the N8P, see Ven. Bodhi's excellent ["Noble Eightfold Path"](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/lib/authors/bodhi/waytoend.html)

Comment: Ven. Bodhi's approach has been to uproot the ignorance. The way according to him teaches opposite of ignorance. I want an approach which uproots the craving. Please dont mind but I will wait for a better answer.

Answer (score 1):

**...How does the Way removes the craving ?...**

The Sammaditthi Sutta promotes a detailed understanding of right view and craving:

> [When, friends, a noble disciple understands the unwholesome, the root of the unwholesome, the wholesome, and the root of the wholesome, in that way he is one of right view,...](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/lib/authors/nanamoli/wheel377.html)

...and discusses the arising of craving at length:

> [With the arising of feeling there is the arising of craving...There are three taints: the taint of sensual desire, the taint of being and the taint of ignorance](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/mn/mn.009.ntbb.html)

However, the Sammaditthi sutta is long and some find the following equivalent and useful for addressing craving:

> [Delight is the root of suffering...](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/mn/mn.001.than.html)
>
> [Displeased, the monks did not delight in the Blessed One's words](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/mn/mn.001.than.html)